# objective c - SKSpriteNode - when touch ends outside of the sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i followed this wonderful guide about mario-style game:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/62053/sprite-kit-tutorial-make-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-2

however, i wanted to convert the movement controls to arrow keys, implemented by SKSpriteNodes with names that are detected by:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
  SKNode* node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

  // other left, up, down arrows with same code here
  if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rightArrow"]) {
    self.player.moveRight = YES;
    self.rightOriginalTouchLocation = location;

   ...
  }
}
```

self.player.moveRight is a boolean value (much like moveForward in the guide), that tells the character at update to move.

it is terminated at:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
  SKNode* node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

  // other left, up, down arrows with same code here
 if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"rightArrow"]) {
    self.player.moveRight = NO;

  }
  ...
}
```

however, i encounter the following problem - when i start the touch on the arrow, drag it outside the arrow, and then release the tap, it is not recognized as 'touch ended' for the arrow node (and it doesn't stop moving because of that).
i tried to solve it in many ways (even calculating touch move distance from original location and see if its too far, then cancel movement), but i always manage to reproduce the constant motion problem.

the issue lies with the fact that i can tap two arrows at the same time, so it is not enough to remember the last node tapped.

since i want to allow movement for different directions at the same time, i cant stop all movements in case one button is dismissed. i need to specifically know which button was released so i can stop that direction's movement only.

do you have any ideas for me? should i implement it in another way considering i want the arrow keys, or is there a method to detect which node is released even though it is not at its original location (of the tap)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Keeping track of 2 different touches that are allowed to move and end independently of one another is more complicated than it sounds. There are a couple of different things to think about: You can get a list of current touches when the touchEnd event gets called, then parse those. Or you can use touchMoved to decide what has changed. You'll need to use all the touches passed to you, not just `[touches anyObject]`, and you'll need parse all the nodes at each location, by using `[self nodesAtPoint: location]`. I haven't come across a built in "I stopped being touched" method for sprites.

Comment: thanks for the comment - i solved my problem i will post as answer

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested about the issue - i had a problem where touching and moving from SKSpriteNode didnt call the touchesEnded for that SKSpriteNode (since the 'release' of the touch was not in the node).

i solved it by keeping the CGPoint of the touch at touchesBegan, and when touchesEnded called, i calculated distances to nearest key using simple distance function:

```
-(int)calculateDistanceWithPoints:(CGPoint)point1 andPoint:(CGPoint)point2 {
  float d = sqrtf(pow((point1.x - point2.x), 2) + pow((point1.y - point2.y), 2));
  return (int)d;
}
```

and then, in touchesEnded, i checked to which key the distance is minimal(i have 3 keys, so which key is most likely to be the key that was 'released') - and did the action required for that key release.

Comment: That's definitely a quick solution, but what happens if the user touches both arrows A and B and then moves both fingers onto arrow B, then only let's up one finger? :-) you now have a user with a finger on arrow B but you did the method for touch up on arrow B and kept the method for arrow A going. You might not care about the edge cases, but there are a lot of them, so just heads up.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up. luckily, the system is for movement, so left and right should never be tapped together. the up arrow is on the other edge of the screen.

The solution is quick and dirty but should be okay :)

Comment: It also won't handle if the use releases both buttons at the same time, but if you do all of you logic in touchMoved, your distance check plus nodes at location might provide the effect you are looking for, since you probably don't want the arrow to be engaged if the user moves the touch far away. Anyways, best of luck.